# Passing through array and then selecting multiple from database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

So I have a table that contains statuses. Each status is shared with a certain username that is shared which is passed through. I want to get all of the groups statuses that a member is joined to. So what I am doing is first getting all of the groups' groupname that the user is a member of. That returns an array and I want to pass that through to a function that returns all statuses from multiple groups. I have to bind the values and don't know how to? Could I put a foreach in the SQL statement? I don't have enough ? for the binding.

Comment: Unless you've done some thing totally weird, should be one query that, need the relevant table schemas though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STOP!

Use a join. You should never have nested loops of queries.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Google it. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html There are plenty of good MySQL tutorials out there. If you post the actual tables someone might be able to help more.